# QlikView - Bar chart - every segment different colors

Tags: colors, bar-chart, qlikview

I have one dimensions and one expressions. is there any way to color every segment (in my example i got 11 segment) in different colors. I now have this

[image: exm.PNG]

and  I want different color for every of this 11 segment.

Does anyone have an idea how to resolve problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Multicolored` checkbox in `Color` tab in the chart properties

[image]

With this checkbox checked the result will be:
[image]

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I have two expression and multicolored is disabled.

Comment: In the expression overview (in the Expressions tab) expand the little `+` sign next to the expression. Double click on "Background Color" and there you can add your color expressions. For example: `if(Category = 'Category1', Green() ...`. If you dont want to depend on categories names you can do: `if( RowNo() = 1, green(), 
if( RowNo() = 2, blue(), ....` and just for the fun this will return random color on every selection `rgb( floor( rand() * 254),  floor( rand() * 254),  floor( rand() * 254))`

Comment: Yes that's it .Thanks a lot